# Why filter: hue-rotate() goes faster through some colors?

Tags: css

When applying an css keyframe animation with linear timing to an element with a hue-rotate(360deg) the animation is going faster through some colors while slower through others. Why?

```
<div class="box" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;"></div>
<style>
.box { animation: hue 10s infinite; } 
@keyframes hue { 0%{filter: hue-rotate(0deg);} 100%{filter: hue-rotate(360deg);}}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) is `ease`, you need to use `linear`

```html
<div class="box" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;background:red"></div>
<style>
  .box {
    animation: hue 10s infinite linear;
  }
  
  @keyframes hue {
    0% {
      filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
</style>
```